# Protracter + Cucumber + TestRail integration

Tags: protractor, cucumber, testrail

What is the best way to integrate Protracter + Cucumber +  TestRail. I tried to find the documentation however it was not able to find any good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems TestRail organize one test case with 3 parts: precondition, test steps and expect results. It not store the Cucumber Feature file directly. But for Cucumber, it rely on feature file as all things start.

I think you need to find out a way to generate Cucumber Feature file according to meta data in TestRail.

There is a Nodejs package: [Node-TestRail](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-testrail) which can call TestRail api to obtain test case meta data, you need to implement an convertor to convert meta data to Cucumber Feature file and save Feature file into a folder in your `Protractor + Cucumber` project (this project should includes step definitions etc)

Now you can execute Protrator script.